# ActiveAdmin Custom Navigation Menu Entry Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Hi i get some behaviour with my AA menu structure which i dont really understand.
I added a custom menu item into AA init file to directly navigate to the `new` action. I got this from the [official documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#adding-custom-menu-items)

`config/initializer/active_admin.rb  :`

```
 config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.build_menu do |menu|
       menu.add :label => "New", priority: 1, :url => 'admin/item/new'
     end
 end
```

But now  i receive the `No route matches [GET] error`. I tried different combinations in the init file, but nothing seem to satisfy my browser.
`rake routes` show that there is the `new` action in the controller matching this route

```
/admin/sms_messages/new(.:format)                   admin/sms_messages#new
```

To make the changes work i always restart webrick. The error message vary like the following:

---

When i have the admin in the path (`menu.add :label => "New", priority: 1, :url => 'admin/item/new'`)

```
Started GET "/admin/item/item/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-30 18:52:33 +0100
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/item/item/new"):
```

---

When omit the admin in the path (`menu.add :label => "New", priority: 1, :url => 'item/new'`)

```
Started GET "/item/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-30 19:00:32 +0100
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/item/new"):
```

---

When i restart the server and clear all cache i can create i can go directly to new `item#new` action. And it works. After pressing submit i get redirected to the show page. From there when i click the Menu item again i get this error:

```
 Started GET "/admin/item/admin/item/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-30 19:20:56 +0100
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/item/admin/item/new"):
```

There is something veryvery wrong with my paths-calls, but i cant figure out where.

However - very unsatisfying - sometimes it works. Hope someone can help me out here! Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

In `config/initializer/active_admin.rb  :`  change

```
 config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.build_menu do |menu|
       menu.add :label => "New", priority: 1, :url => 'admin/item/new'
     end
 end
```

to (change the URL path)

```
 config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.build_menu do |menu|
       menu.add :label => "New", priority: 1, :url => '/admin/item/new'
     end
 end
```

Comment: OK i got the solution. In the init file `'admin/item/new'` has to be `'/admin/item/new'`. The slash!! (: Now all navigation works as expected.